# Simple Jquery audio visualizator

Tags: jquery, html, visualizer

So I have a music site where you can just listen to songs that I've put in my playlist.And I just wanted to make just a detail more that suits my site.And what I'm after is a audio visualizator.You know those little bars in a music player that jump up and down when the music is playing.So I'm wondering if there's a simple plugin that let's you do that.I've found a couple visualizators, they're basically just backgournds with particles that move dependant on music.I just want a couple of small bars.My site does'nt play `<audio>` elements, it's a javascript music player with a playlist.

If you have any unclearances please ask I will try to answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 Audio Visualizer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3351147/html5-audio-visualizer)

Comment: https://github.com/jsantell/dancer.js